# selectively disable automatic download of updates of i386 packages information in repositories

Tags: updates

How is it possible to selectively disable automatic download of updates (after sudo apt-get update) of only i386 packages information in repositories in Ubuntu 15.10 64 bit?

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

if you're sure you don't want updates to any 32-bit applications present on your system or to install 32-bit applications. Keep in mind that you'll be blocking security updates for any existing 32-bit applications.

And, later, if you change your mind and want to install 32-bit applications or to update existing ones, run:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```